# How do we show a table view inside a UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uialertview

I am trying to add a UITableView inside my UIAlertView and its not showing up. I just see title & message along with "OK" button on alertview.

Below is my code and I am running on iOS 7.

```
- (void)showDataReceivedAlert {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Received Data" message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 40, 264, 120)];
    table.delegate = self;
    table.dataSource = self;
    table.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [alert addSubview:table];
    [alert show];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)iSection {
    return 6;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"iBeaconDataCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [iTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    NSString *cellText;
    NSString *cellLabelText;

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *encodedObject = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"data"];
    MyObj *myData = (MyObj *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];

    switch (iIndexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cellText = @"Data 1";
            cellLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myData.data1];
            break;
        case 1:
            cellText = @"Data 2";
            cellLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myData.data2];
            break;
        case 2:
            cellText = @"Data 3";
            cellLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myData.data3];
            break;
        case 3:
            cellText = @"Data 4";
            cellLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myData.data4];
            break;
        case 4:
            cellText = @"Data 5";
            cellLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", myData.data5];
            break;
        case 5:
            cellText = @"Data 6";
            cellLabelText = myData.data6;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = cellText;

    UILabel *cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 150.0, 44.0)];
    cellLabel.text = cellLabelText;
    cell.accessoryView = cellLabel;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You don't. `UIAlertView` has never supported adding subviews. It worked somewhat in previous versions of iOS but not at all in iOS 7. You need your own custom alert view to do this properly.

Comment: In one of the WWDC 2013 sessions they mentioned that they were adding a content view that you could add a subview to, but, unfortunately it seems they decided to cancel this.

Comment: it is very userful if u want to use uitable view with alert view https://github.com/blommegard/SBTableAlert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The default alert isn't meant to take subviews.** (while in ios6 and earlier add. subviews could be hacked in, this does NOT work in iOS7)

**write your own custom UIView that looks and acts like an alert.**

There's a lot of implementations around if you prefer not to do it yourself :) e.g. on cocoacontrols.com

Comment: I have implemented my own custom view to look alike UIAlertView.

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 7 you need to add like this

[alertview setValue:tableView forKey:@"accessoryView"];